# Search function works, but displays random data when search is performed

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I have a very simple search script installed and it does what it's supposed to, except when it returns the results, it displays this information before the returned data results:

object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(36) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Is there something I can do so this doesn't occur?

Here is the search.php page:

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx") or die('Error connection');
  $data = '';
  if(isset($_POST['search']))
  {
$keyword = $_POST['search'];
$keyword = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$keyword);
$query = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY name";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
var_dump($result);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count>0)
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$data = $data."<div>".$row['name']."</div>";
}
  }

?>

<?php echo $data; ?>
```

Figured this out!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Without any ORDER BY clause the results are always going to be in an arbitrary order.  SQL promises to return correct sets, but sets don't have to be in any particular order unless you explicitly specify otherwise.

Comment: @GordonM I updated the above code here as well as on the page with an ORDER BY clause.  Still displays that data when the search is performed and returning results, however.

Comment: BTW, don't use MySQL LIKE if this is a real app. If you need search create a fulltext index in MySQL or use something like Solr/Elasticsearch.

Comment: @DougT. I don't think I need anything as big as Elasticsearch - this is for a text RPG game and the search is simply to search for a character or player name.  That's why I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: Take out the var_dump($result).